# Sql Server, how can I return result where records stamped last month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, between

I am trying to return count of all record that where stamped as completed last month. the column name actualend his a datetime field. it is the same field where i need to make sure the record is completed in last month.

This is what I have

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM PhoneCall AS p WITH (nolock) 
WHERE   ( p.actualend >= CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(dd, - (DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, GETDATE())) - 1), DATEADD(mm, - 1, GETDATE())), 1) AS datetime)) 
  AND ( p.actualend <= CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)), 1) AS datetime))
```

this code give me slightly higher results (total results i get it 847)

But if I run this code

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM PhoneCall AS p WITH (nolock) 
WHERE p.actualend BETWEEN '03/01/2013 00:00:00' AND '03/31/2013 23:59:59'
```

I get a total of 843 records. 
how can I correct my first query to get the same total in both queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query doesn't get all the records stamped complete on the last day. This is because the calculation of the last day return the correct date with the time of 12:00:00 AM. You want the time part to be 11:59:59 PM.

To test out the logic in your query I ran a select statement to see what the calculations of the first and last day of the previous month were:

```
select CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(dd, - (DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, GETDATE())) - 1), DATEADD(mm, - 1, GETDATE())), 1) AS datetime)
select CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)), 1) AS datetime)
```

The results were `2013-04-01 00:00:00.000`  and `2013-04-30 00:00:00.000`. (Based on the current date of 5/7/2013)

I recommend calculating the first day of the current month instead of the last day of the previous month and then doing a `<` comparison instead of an `<=` comparison. Then you don't have to deal with what happens if the recorded is stamped complete in the last few milliseconds of the day.

I modified your original query below by adding 1 day to the calculation of the end of the month -- effectively calculating the first day of the current month. Then I changed the comparison operator to `1` instead of `<=`. You probably could improve this calculation, but this was just a quick and easy way to show an example of the logic.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM PhoneCall AS p WITH (nolock) 
WHERE ( p.actualend >= CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(dd, - (DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, GETDATE())) - 1), DATEADD(mm, - 1, GETDATE())), 1) AS datetime))
  AND ( p.actualend < CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)), 1) AS datetime) + 1)
```

Comment: thanks you Adam for leading me to the correct path. Here is what I have done and it worked  p.actualend BETWEEN CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(dd, - (DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, GETDATE())) - 1), DATEADD(mm, - 1, GETDATE())), 1) AS datetime)
 AND    CAST(    DATEADD( s, 86399, CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)), 1)) AS datetime)

Answer (score 1):

Adam has a correct answer.  I think, however, that it could be done in such a way to make it easier to understand.

The gist of selecting data between two dates, is to use this logic, which is in Adam's 2nd query.

```
where YourField >= @StartDate
and YourField < the day after @EndDate
```

If you are calling this query from an application (.net, php, coldfusion, etc), it might be simpler to create those variables in your application and send them as parameters.  Otherwise, you might want to do something like this:

```
  declare @EndDate as datetime;
  declare @StartDate as datetime;

  set @EndDate = CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8)
  , DATEADD(dd, - (DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, GETDATE())) - 1)
 , DATEADD(mm, 0, GETDATE())), 1) AS datetime);

 set @StartDate = DateAdd(month, -1, @EndDate);

 SELECT count(*) 
 FROM lassqls1.CareCredit_MSCRM.dbo.PhoneCall AS p WITH (nolock) 
 WHERE p.actualend >= @StartDate
 and p.actualend < @EndDate
```